# What is the distribution of a point to a random line?

Tags: distributions, density-function, variable

Let's say that we have a random vector that represents a line [A,B,C] so that, Ax + By + c = 0. A, B, and C are independent Normally distributed random variables, with different mean and variances. if we have a point (x_0, y_0)
The distance of this point the the line is

$$Z=\frac{|Ax_0+By_0+C|}{\sqrt{A^2 + B^2}}$$
What would the distribution of Z be?

Comment: $Z^2$ follows a generalization of the [doubly-noncentral F-ratio distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_F-distribution), which already has four parameters.  (With some simplifications, it can be reduced to consideration of just  two additional parameters.)  Thus, (1) don't expect there to be any convenient formulas and (2) if this has arisen in a problem, it would help to narrow the possibilities if you can.

Comment: In a noncentral F-ratio distribution, the numerator and denominator must be independent, I don't think that is the case with Z, because A and B are in both the numerator and denominator, thus should be dependent.

Comment: That's right: but in some cases (such as when $x_0=y_0=0$) the numerator and denominator are indeed independent, demonstrating how the noncentral F distribution is a special case of this one.  Right away that shows the answer to your question will be (substantially) more complicated than a noncentral F.